# Need to update the data the comming from one webservice in Async Task with other Async Task

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

I have an android activity where I am calling a web-service using `AsyncTask` and when the data is received success fully I need to update each row or item received form the web-service with the data coming from another web-service. This second web-service is called based on the data from first web-service. Its like this:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try
    {
        String line="";
        //  String ur = "http://"+ServerDetails.hostServer+"/appservices.svc/TaskQuanityList?MaterialID=9336&ProjectNo=51&TaskNo=51." ;
        String ur = "http://"+ServerDetails.hostServer+"/appservices.svc/grn?po="+PONum;

        Log.d("URL", ur);

        // Replace it with your own WCF service path
        URL json = new URL(ur);
        URLConnection jc = json.openConnection();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(jc.getInputStream()));

        line = reader.readLine().toString();

        Log.d("LINE",line);
        line=line.replace("\\\"", "\"");
        line=line.substring(1, line.length()-1) ;
        JSONArray array=new JSONArray(line);

        for(int i=0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject tmpJson=array.getJSONObject(i);
            lstdrpItem=new ArrayList<DropItem>();

            StoreAsync storeasc=new StoreAsync();another webservice
            storeasc.execute(tmpJson.getString("MaterialNo"));//-->Here I am calling second webservice

            ItmGrn=new GrnData(tmpJson.getString("lblRowIdField"),tmpJson.getString("MaterialName"),tmpJson.getString("MaterialNo"),tmpJson.getString("RecievedQty"),tmpJson.getString("qty"),tmpJson.getString("Conversion_Factor"),tmpJson.getString("GRN_NO"),tmpJson.getString("Good_Qty"),tmpJson.getString("Retain_Qty"),tmpJson.getString("Rejected_Qty"),tmpJson.getString("Challan_Qty"),tmpJson.getString("RecStore_No"),tmpJson.getString("Brand_Id"),lstdrpItem);
            lstGrn.add(ItmGrn);
            Log.d("Material Name",tmpJson.getString("MaterialName"));
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("ERRROR--->",e.getMessage());
    }

    return  "" ;
}
```

Now the issue is, it goes on executing the loop iterations without waiting for the second web-service. Now my question is how to make it wait until second web-service gets the data and continue with remaining iterations in the loop?

Comment: Post your StoreAsync class. In that you can add listener for your second webservice which will be executed after your second webservice completes its operation. If you post the code, I can help you.

Comment: You can add a function in your in your first `AsyncTask` class which does the work of your second `AsyncTask` and call that function by passing necessary parameters.

Comment: but that function also needs to return the value to the loop but there is also async task . My question is how to stop execution till async task completes

Comment: What I am suggesting is a sequential approach. It's like calling function B from A, so function A will wait till function B finishes. Here, B should not be an AsyncTask and both functions should be in the same class. So, function B will contain the actual code (not calling the other AsyncTask) of `doInBackground()` method of your second AsyncTask.